# My spare key to my 2011 VW eso stopped working how do I reprogram it?

Tags: ignition, ignition-key

It is a keyless ignition, I tried YouTube but I couldn’t find what I needed can you help?

Comment: Get a copy of the workshop manual - the process will be in there. I have a pdf one for my car and it is there...

Comment: What's a VW "eso?" Do you mean "Eos?"